# AWS Lambda Java

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

When deploying a function from eclipse that needs to access an amazon service (dynamodb for example) i add the aws sdk library in project build path in order to gain access to aws services. This however results to a big jar which in result leads to big upload time in order to deploy and test the function.
Is there an other way in order to make the jar lighter ?

Comment: You should give more details about what are you doing. Sizes maybe, what was included in your project.

Comment: thx for the reply.I am trying to add an item to dynamodb from the lambda function. I am asking if there is another way than to include the whole aws sdk library.

Comment: Yes, you could just include the DynamoDB module, this will substantially reduce the size of your JAR. https://java.awsblog.com/post/TxBSZ02ZOG3VPZ/AWS-SDK-for-Java-Maven-Modules

Comment: hello, that was exactly what i was looking for. Thank you, off to try it.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use "**maven**" to add only the required dependencies.
It will effectively reduce your **jar** size.

For required dependencies you can check the link given below:
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could exclude all undesired libs from one specific dependency in pom.xml. Using this tag:

```
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
      <groupId>sample.ProjectB</groupId>
      <artifactId>Project-B</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use any Amazon services with Lambda function you don't have to include AWS-sdk library like AWS or even AWS-DynamoDB in project, simply add the reference for the AWS services you want to use.

As AWS Lambda is configured to use AWS-sdk libraries. If you are using services other than AWS then you have to include the supporting libraries.